spring boot 2.5.x and gradle 8 missing boot jar
So i seem to be missing the creation of the boot jar when i use spring boot 2.5 with gradle 8.
> Task :clean
> Task :checkKotlinGradlePluginConfigurationErrors
> Task :compileKotlin NO-SOURCE
> Task :compileJava
> Task :processResources
> Task :classes
> Task :jar
> Task :assemble
> Task :compileTestKotlin NO-SOURCE

when i upgrade to spring boot 2.7, then boot jar is called
> Task :clean
> Task :checkKotlinGradlePluginConfigurationErrors
> Task :compileKotlin NO-SOURCE
> Task :processResources
> Task :classes
> Task :bootJarMainClassName
> Task :bootJar

im not sure why this is a problem. Its a very basic java application
kotlin("jvm") version "1.9.20"
id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.5.3"
id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.11.RELEASE"
id("org.liquibase.gradle") version "2.1.1"

does anyone know how I can get the bootJar to generate.

afaik Spring Boot 2.5 doesn't support Gradle 8 or at least not the most recent versions. Plugins and APIs have changed and the Spring Boot plugin for that version is simply not build for those.

Use appropriate versions and everything will be fine.
For Spring Boot 2.5 they are
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.8.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2021-01-22 13:20:08 UTC
Revision:     31f14a87d93945024ab7a78de84102a3400fa5b2

Kotlin:       1.4.20
Groovy:       2.5.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.9 compiled on September 27 2020
JVM:          1.8.0_412 (Private Build 25.412-b08)
OS:           Linux 6.5.0-35-generic amd64

and then
> Task :clean
> Task :compileJava
> Task :processResources
> Task :classes
> Task :bootJarMainClassName
> Task :bootJar
> Task :jar
> Task :assemble
> Task :compileTestJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :processTestResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :testClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :test NO-SOURCE
> Task :check UP-TO-DATE
> Task :build

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 896ms
6 actionable tasks: 6 executed

